# Convert objects to a string value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery.each(input, function(key, value){
    jQuery('<div/>', {
        class: 'info',
        id: value.id,
        text: jQuery('<div/>', {class: 'image', text: '<img src="'+value.image+'">'})+jQuery('<div/>', {class: 'text_data', text: value.name})
    }).appendTo('#list');
});
```

Is it possible somehow to convert objects to string in `text` attribute (should to be no cycles). If needed can be wrapped by a function.

**UPDATE:**

```
<div class="info" id="29">[object Object][object Object]</div>
<div class="info" id="30">[object Object][object Object]</div>
<div class="info" id="31">[object Object][object Object]</div>
```

So i need to update this line `jQuery('<div/>', {class: 'image', text: '<img src="'+value.image+'">'})+jQuery('<div/>', {class: 'text_data', text: value.name})` that there would be a string.

Comment: are you trying to change value.image to string?

Comment: Try replacing `text` with `html`. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "to string".

Comment: $('<div>').append($('#item-of-interest').clone()).html();

Comment: @RachelGallen I think that's the answer he wants

Comment: Explain what does: _"convert objects to string in text attribute (should to be no cycles)"_ mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll expand on Rachel's answer

You are creating two elements here

```
jQuery('<div/>', {class: 'image', text: '<img src="'+value.image+'">'})+jQuery('<div/>', {class: 'text_data', text: value.name})
```

To get it as a string.. create an container element and append those two elements.. so you can get it back as a html string by calling .html()

```
$('<div/>') // create a div container
   .append(jQuery('<div/>', {class: 'image', text: '<img src="'+value.image+'">'})) // append objects
   .append(jQuery('<div/>', {class: 'text_data', text: value.name}))
   .html() // <-- now you have it as a string
```

Comment: I suspect the OP actually does not want a string, just the div with appended elements.

Comment: @Bergi yes, you are right.

Comment: Also thanks for answer, not the 100%, but i found what i need.

Comment: @Bergi Oh.. his example is confusing then since he's passing it to the text property for his newly created div.. so I suspected that he wanted a String

Comment: @wirey in jQuery docs i found only `text` so i thought it would be right, but not...

Comment: Ah ok.. I was going to create a fiddle earlier but I'm guessing you already have it all figured out :)

Comment: @wirey except what images still showing as a string.

Comment: @Kirix change it to html instead of text also

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 $('<div>').append($('#item-of-interest').clone()).html();
```

Comment: please see my post once more.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `JSON.stringify`, which serializes an object. Most modern browsers support this method naively, but for those that don't, you can include a JS version:

```
var obj = {
  name: 'myObj'
};

JSON.stringify(obj);
```